# How to use for loop for login in karate framework

Tags: karate

Feature: Login
Background:
 * url ''

- def users = function(i){ return karate.call("classpath:v1/login.feature", 
  { "username": 'shameem', 
  "password":  'shameen' ,
  "ipAddress": "string",
  "macAddress": "string",
  "machineName": "string"})
- def usersResult = karate.repeat(2, users )
- match each usersResult[*].responseStatus == 200

Given url ''
And request users
When method post
Then status 200

- def Insert = response
- print Insert
- print 'created Insert is: ' + Insert.Message

Comment: Maybe it is better to use the `Scenario Outline`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-cucumber-way